# Can I get a list of templates of a Liferay Site?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to get a **list of all templates** (JournalArticle templates in [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Velocity) or [FTL](http://freemarker.org/)) of a Liferay Site in a *WCM Template* or *Theme template*.

This is what I tried:

```
<#assign DDMTemplateLocalServiceUtil = objectUtil("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatamapping.service.DDMTemplateLocalServiceUtil") />
<#assign ClassNameLocalServiceUtil = objectUtil("com.liferay.portal.service.ClassNameLocalServiceUtil")/>

<#assign className = ClassNameLocalServiceUtil.getClassName("com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle") />
<#assign classNameId = className.getClassNameId() />
<#assign groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId() />

<#assign ddmTemplates = DDMTemplateLocalServiceUtil.getTemplates(groupId, classNameId) />
<#list ddmTemplates as template>
    ${template.getName()}
</#list>
```

But I don't get any value and no error.

When I try to get the name of a template based on its id, it works:

```
<#assign ddmTemplate = DDMTemplateLocalServiceUtil.getTemplate(50367) />
${ddmTemplates.getName()}
```

I don't know the templates id, so how can I get all templates of a Liferay Site without knowing their id?

Comment: Just a remark: `${template.getName()}` will return an XML snippet, for the name you need to use `${template.getName(locale)}`

Comment: Did you check if groupId is the correct one? I'd guess that the scopeGroupId could be a different one from those where the templates reside.

Comment: please check group id,as for one of the issues,on lIferay 6.2 ,themeDisplay  was not resolving correctly,better to get groupId,directly available as a default variable.

Comment: My groupId is **20182** and `themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId()` or `groupId` gives me that value. So I think is not a problem of groupId. I also tried to pass parameter manually `getTemplates(20182, classNameId)`

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal I found that the problem is in `className.getClassNameId()`. My article classId is 20102 but `ClassNameLocalServiceUtil` gives me this value: 20109 and I don't know why is different..